# How to fillter Cart Price Rules by website id?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to get active sales rule which is valid and filter Cart Price Rules by website id as the store is multi-website so try using bellow code but getting an error

My Code

```
protected $sales_rule;
    protected $rule;
    protected $search_builder;
    protected $store;
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,\Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $sales_rule,\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $search_builder, \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $rule,array $data = array(), \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder){
        $this->sales_rule=$sales_rule;
        $this->search_builder=$search_builder;
        $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
        $this->rule = $rule;
        $this->store=$context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getPromoDetail(){
        $sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder->setField('to_date')->setDirection('ASC')->create();
        $searchCriteria = $this->search_builder->addFilter('website_id',$this->store->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),'eq')->addFilter('is_active',1,'eq')->addFilter('is_popup_rule',1,'eq')->setSortOrders([$sortOrder])->create();
        $items = $this->sales_rule->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        if(count($items)):
            return current($items);
        endif;
        return false;
    }
```

Error

**Fehler beim Filtern der Vorlage: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'website_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `rule_coupons`.`code` FROM `salesrule` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `salesrule_coupon` AS `rule_coupons` ON main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND rule_coupons.is_primary = 1 WHERE ((`website_id` = '1')) AND ((`is_active` = 1)) AND ((`is_popup_rule` = 1)) ORDER BY to_date ASC**

purpose of code is I want to display active coupon code in a popup so write code for getting Cart price rule and display in pop...

any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem and since the information on the websites are stored on another table I used a ugly but functional query to retrieve the rules Ids:

```
    use \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
    use \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    protected $resourceConnection;
    /**
     * @var MetadataPool
     */
    protected $metadataPool;

    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        Metapool $metadataPool
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool
    }

    public function getRulesIds(int $websiteId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection */
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $salesRuleTable = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('salesrule');
        $salesRuleWebsiteTable = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('salesrule_website');
        $metadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(RuleInterface::class);
        $linkField = $metadata->getLinkField();

        $sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM $salesRuleTable as `sr`
            LEFT JOIN $salesRuleWebsiteTable as `srw`
                ON `sr`.`$linkField` = `srw`.`$linkField`
            LEFT JOIN $salesRuleCouponTable as `src`
                ON `sr`.`rule_id` = `src`.`rule_id`
            WHERE
                `sr`.`is_active` = ?
            AND
                `srw`.`website_id` = ?
        ";

        return $connection->fetchCol($sql, [1, $websiteId]);
    }
```

I know it is definitely not the cleanest solution but in my case I had also to check some values on a couple of additional joined tables and this was the quickest way